# How can I change the colors used by the Code Coverage Analyzer in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-coverage

I frequently use the Visual Studio 2012 Code Coverage Analyzer with the Code Coloring. This works great when using the light theme. But when I use the dark theme, it is hard to distinguished between the colors. I can't find a setting that will allow me to change the colors for the Code Coverage.

Can I change the colors? If there is a setting, where is it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the main menu, go to Tools | Options.
Then from the treeview, choose Environment -> Fonts and Colors.
And in "Display items" choose "Coverage Not Touched Area", "Coverage Partially Touched Area" and "Coverage Touched Area". There you can change the default item background.

In the german version you have to look up at "V" like in "Von Codeabdeckung..."

Answer (score 1):

In addition, if you use JetBrains dotcover, they have cretaed their own setting in the options of jetbrains

Resharper>Options>DotCover>Highlighting.

Their values are nice.